# Index match or concatenate or VBA? How to correlate one dated occurrence to another, prior dated occurrence?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, concatenation, vba

I have multiple variables on two worksheets that I need to compare and return a value if it matches a dated range criteria.  My worksheets look like this:

Worksheet A

```
Location    DIST_PO_NUMBER  Order Date  Part #  DIST_UPC
```

Worksheet B

```
Location    ORIG_DIST_CAT_ID    Part #  DIST_UPC    STOCKOUT_DATE
```

I tried using an IndexMatch with the following forumla, but it provided no results:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(Stockouts!E:E, MATCH('Items Ordered'!D2&'Items Ordered'!A2&C2, Stockouts!B:B&Stockouts!E:E)),"Regular Order")}
```

I think I should probably use CONCATENATE to combine the Location and Part # values, but the dates will never match.  In this scenario, the final column on Worksheet 2 "STOCKOUT_DATE" may trigger the order, and the dates could be up to 7 days apart.

How can I correlate the Stockout date to the Order date?  I want to show where an order was triggered most likely due to a stockout.

Comment: It would help us understand better if you would put some data in the examples and expected outcome.

Comment: @ScottCraner:  Location data would be Warehouse A, Warehouse B, Warehouse C    Order Date would be the dated data       and Part # would be a1220  b2468  c4569 d3256    Expected outcome would be to correlate the dated data in Worksheet A (Items Ordered) with the dated data on Worksheet B (Stockouts) that happened any time during the previous 7 days with the same part # and location.  I am attempting to correlate an item stockout with a subsequent item purchase.

Comment: @pnuts 'Items Ordered" is Worksheet A; "Stockouts" is Worksheet B.  The dates are sorted from newest to oldest.